# how to create table number columns use python to bigquery load_table_from_dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i want to bigquery table from python.bigquery
dataframe have number columns like '333115'
when i user load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_path)

error occur

```
400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/paprika-cada/jobs?uploadType=multipart: Invalid field name "`3117539507`". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.
```

if mysql create number columns use ``
but in python dataframe how to do that?

Comment: As the error indicates, bigquery does not allow column name to start with numbers. It could either start with letter or underscore. You have to rename the column in your application before loading into the table. Please find the link to corresponding documentation on column names : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Google's official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names), the column names in Bigquery can start with only letters or underscore, hence you're receiving such error.

As suggested by @adhithiyan, you'll have to change the column name before loading your data into BigQuery.